# Pattern matcher in Java

Tags: java, regex

I want a result from a pattern matcher like this

```
finalResult = "1. <b>Apple</b> - Apple is a fruit 2. <b>Caw</b> - Caw is an animal 3. <b>Parrot</b> - Parrot is a bird";
```

And I tried this way:

```
        String test = "1. Apple - Apple is a fruit 2. Caw - Caw is an animal 3. Parrot - Parrot is a bird";
        String finalResult = "";

        Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("\\d\\.(.+?)-");
        Matcher mat = pat.matcher(test);

        int count = 0;
        while(mat.find()){
            finalResult += test.replaceAll(mat.group(count), "<b>" + mat.group(count) + "</b>");
            count++;
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can directly use `test.replaceAll()` instead of using `Pattern.matcher()`, since `replaceAll()` accepts regex on its own.

And the regex to use would be like `"(?<=\\d\\. )(\\w*?)(?= - )"`.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/kA2iK4/1)

So you code would be

```
String test = "1. Apple - Apple is a fruit 2. Caw - Caw is an animal 3. Parrot - Parrot is a bird";
String finalResult = "";
finalResult = test.replaceAll("(?<=\\d\\. )(\\w*?)(?= - )", "<b>" + "$1" + "</b>");
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use `replaceAll` method of the `Matcher` class. ([javadoc](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/regex/Matcher.html#replaceAll-java.lang.String-))

Code:

```
String test = "1. Apple - Apple is a fruit 2. Caw - Caw is an animal 3. Parrot - Parrot is a bird";
String finalResult = "";

Pattern pat = Pattern.compile("(\\d+)\\.\\s(.+?)\\s-");
Matcher mat = pat.matcher(test);

if (mat.find()){
     finalResult = mat.replaceAll("$1. <b>$2</b> -");
}

System.out.println(finalResult);
```

`replace all` substitutes all matches of the string with specified regex. `$1` and `$2` are captured groups (for example '1' and 'Apple' for for first element of list).

I slightly changed your regex:

1. `(\\d+)` captures multidigital numbers (not only 0-9). Also, it 'saves' it in group 1
2. Added `\\s` symbols, which match whitespace symbols

Answer (score 0):

@Codebender 's solution is more compact, but you could always use the `String.split()` method:

```
    String test = "1. Apple - Apple is a fruit 2. Caw - Caw is an animal 3. Parrot - Parrot is a bird";

    String[]tokens = test.split("-\\s*|\\d\\.\\s*");
    StringBuffer result = new StringBuffer();
    int idx = 1;
    while (idx < (tokens.length - 1))
    {
        result.append("<b>" + tokens[idx++].trim() + "</b> - " + tokens[idx++].trim() + ". ");
    }
    System.out.println(result);
```