# Make certain characters of a word from string bold

Tags: php, regex

I need to highlight a certain characters from a string,
I tried str_replace and preg_replace. But these work only if full word is entered,

```
$text = str_replace($searhPhrase, '<b>'.$searhPhrase.'</b>',  $text);
$text = preg_replace('/('. $searhPhrase .')/i', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
```

I want something like, if I search for 'and' even the letters from 'hand' should get highlighted.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Could this be the same assignment (asked 30 minutes earlier): [http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606124/pattern-matcher-in-java](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31606124/pattern-matcher-in-java)

Comment: Just to get this right: You do want to highlight the whole word, if the search phrase occurs in it? So, "hand" should be replaced with "<b>hand</b>" and NOT with "h<b>and</b>"?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

```
$text = preg_replace('/\S*('. $searhPhrase .')\S*/i', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
```

This should do it for you.

or

if you want to highlight the whole word

```
$text = preg_replace('/(\S*'. $searhPhrase .'\S*)/i', '<b>$1</b>', $text);
```

Comment: ☕ I'd rather use such as `\w*tea\w*` and replace with `\0`

Comment: @Jonny5 not much into `perl` :P you can add yours though :) gonna grab a ☕ now that you have reminded me :P

Comment: Oh, no [I meant this](https://regex101.com/r/pU0fT3/2) just to use `\w` word character instead of `\S` and drop capture group, replace with `<b>$0</b>` :D but never mind, enjoy tea!

Comment: Or after another cup [even like this](https://regex101.com/r/pU0fT3/5) `[\w-]*tea['\w-]*`

Answer (score 0):

if this still not works try with this Function

```
function strReplace($searchText,$mainText){
    return str_replace($searchText, '<b>'.$searchText.'</b>', $mainText);
  }
```